# invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm receiving erros when I try and update a field. The field is a simple decimal field and I get no errors when entering "9.5" for example, but when I just enter "9" I receive this:

```
invalid input syntax for integer: "9.0"
```

Comment: What does the model look like? Any validation? What version of Rails/PG? etc.

Comment: Works just fine in plain SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/11d07/1 probably something with your obfuscation layer (aka ORM)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `9.0 !== 9`

Try to cast it, `9.0::int`

```
select 9.0::float, 9.0::int;
 float8 | int4
--------+------
      9 |    9
(1 row)
```